# model is not bound angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

Attempting to bind a single model to two controllers to be updated simultaneously.Then using a  tag the relevant value of the model is shown.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body >
    <div ng-app="" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.msg">
        <h1>{{model.msg}}</h1>

        <div ng-controller="firstController">
            <input type="text" ng-model="model.msg">
            <h1>{{model.msg}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="secondController">
            <input type="text" ng-model="model.msg">
            <h1>{{model.msg}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="controller/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dependancies/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
function firstController($scope){}

function secondController($scope){}
```

Comment: Err. So, *what's your question*?

Answer (score 0):

`model.msg` property is bound to controller scope. If you want to share data between controllers use Angular Factory/Service